# Does there exist a bijective mapping $f: \Delta\to\mathbb{C} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exist a bijective mapping $f: \Delta\to\mathbb{C} $?

Yet I have not found such example. Is it false (why?),please help me.
$ \Delta $ is the unit disk in $\mathbb {C}$.

Comment: How are you defining $\Delta$

Comment: $\Delta $ means unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Unit circle or unit disk?

Comment: Do you require the map to be biholomorphic, or just bijective?

Comment: just bijective mapping

Comment: ($\Delta$ is standard notation for the unit disc. http://planetmath.org/UnitDisk)

Comment: A continuous $f$ cannot exist, since $\Delta$ is compact and $\mathbb{C}$ is not. Surely a biholomorphic cannot exist.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this radius by radius. So in case we were talking about the open disk, all we’d need to do is get a nice map from $[0,1\rangle$ onto $[0,\infty\rangle$, like $x/(1-x)$. In case we were talking about the closed disk, you need a (discontinuous) map from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1\rangle$, and follow it by the map you chose before. For this discontinuous map, one might send $1/n$ to $1/(n+1)$ for all $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 2):

1) I'll assume $\Delta$ is the unit circle first, since that's what you said in a comment above. Remove $1$ from the unit circle, and $(0,0)$ from the complex plane. Then take the polar coordinates. You see your question amounts to finding a bijection between $(0,2\pi)$ and $(0,+\infty)\times [0,2\pi)$. I will take for granted that for every interval which is not a singleton, there exists a bijection with $(0,1)$ ([see here](http://www.math.montana.edu/~geyer/2008/fall/361/key3.pdf) if you want to construct such bijections). Now the problem is equivalent to finding a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1)^2$.

Recall that every real number $x$ has a unique proper decimal expansion $x=x_0,x_1x_2\ldots$ By proper, I mean that the sequence of decimals is not eventually equal to $9$. Now the function 
$$
(0.x_1x_2\ldots,0.y_1y_2\ldots)\longmapsto 0.x_1y_1x_2y_2\ldots
$$
defines an injection of $(0,1)^2$ into $(0,1)$. It is easy to get an injection of $(0,1)$ into $(0,1)^2$. By [Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Bernstein%E2%80%93Schroeder_theorem), there exists a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1)^2$.

2) If $\Delta$ is the open unit disk now (which would make more sense notationwise), [you can find](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76642/an-homeomorphism-from-the-plane-to-the-disc) a homeomorphism between $\Delta$ and $\mathbb{C}$. Note that you can't find a biholomorphism, due to Liouville.

Comment: Is the open disk really biholomorphic with the complex plane?

Comment: @Lubin Ah! Silly me! Thanks.

Comment: You might want to include that such a biholomorhpic map cannot exist, by Liouville's theorem.

Comment: I do not think that $g$ is a bijection, since nothing is mapped to 0.0909090909.... Luckily we have Cantor-Bernstein theorem we only need injective maps in both directions. This is almost the same mistake as the one made famously by Cantor (and noticed by Dedekind), see, for example, Dauben, [p.55-57](http://books.google.com/books?id=-cpFeTPJXDIC&pg=PA56).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Good point, thanks a lot.